# Ormlite Join 3 Tables (Many-to-Many)

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm trying to create search interface via ORMLite in Android. There are 3 tables created, that are making many-to-many relationship. (Recipe >> RecipesForTag << Tag)

```
tagQueryBuilder.where()
    .like(Tag.COLUMN_NAME, "%" + text + "%");

recipesForTagQueryBuilder
    .joinOr(tagQueryBuilder);

recipeQueryBuilder
    .joinOr(recipesForTagQueryBuilder)
    ...other joins
    .where()
    .like(Recipe.COLUMN_TITLE, "%" + text + "%");

PreparedQuery<Recipe> preparedQuery = recipeQueryBuilder.prepare();

return recipeDao.query(preparedQuery);
```

When I'm not using line with `.joinOr(recipesForTagQueryBuilder)` everything is working fine. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK my bad.
The only thing that was bad was using joinOr while I needed leftJoinOr... The question has one main problem: when middle table is empty no result will be find (also when ...other joins is nonempty). So result is simple:

```
recipesForTagQueryBuilder
    .leftJoinOr(tagQueryBuilder);

recipeQueryBuilder
    .leftJoinOr(recipesForTagQueryBuilder)
```

Comment: Can you please explain that?